# Powershell how to fix/program auto logging "Property 'value' cannot be found on this object"

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Good Morning

I am very new to Powershell and practicing how to code.

I try to make automated logging system.

My Power Shell is Version: 2.0.

Thanks to this person.

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Open-Internet-Explorer-e4f8ae4b

```
# Invoke Internet Explorer 

$IE = New-Object -com internetexplorer.application; 
$IE.visible = $true; 
$IE.navigate($Url); 

# Wait a few seconds and then launch the executable. 

while ($IE.Busy -eq $true) 

{ 

Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 2000; 

} 

$IE.Document.getElementById(“username”).value = $Username 
$IE.Document.getElementByID(“password”).value=  $Password 
$IE.getElementsByClassName("btnLogin").Click()
```

I am having two errors which I do not know how to fix

The one is

"Property 'value' cannot be found on this object; make sure it exists and is settable."

```
$IE.Document.getElementById(“username”).value = $Username 
$IE.Document.getElementByID(“password”).value=  $Password
```

I am using Google Chrome and left click "inspect" in the boxes and seeing "username" and "password" on IDs

and the another one is

Property 'value' cannot be found on this object; make sure it exists and is settable.

```
$IE.getElementsByClassName("btnLogin").Click()
```

Since there is no ID=..... so I took "input class = "btnLogin"

There are causing errors, how can I fix these issues?

Thanks

Comment: Hi, can you please provide sample HTML code from the login page? Please edit your question to include this.

Comment: The DOM method names are case-sensitive, change `getElementByID()` to `getElementById()` for the password field. `getElementsByClassName()` returns a collection of elements, you may need to do `getElementsByClassName("btnLogin")[0].Click()`

Comment: This is worthwhile, although it's not an answer.  Learn how to use the "gm" command.  You have to pipe something to it, and it will tell you, among other things, what properties it has.